# Stretch DIV to full page width but also make it auto resize according to browsers borders

Tags: html, css

[image: Requirement]

How can I make this layout to be fully responsive?
Basically I need both boxes:

## chatEntries and #chatUsers  to be sctretched across whole page.

They must share page width in ratio of: 85% [chatEntries] - 15% [chatUsers].

So how would I do this?

Comment: **Responsive** is not the correct term, you are describing a **fluid layout**. Responsive would be if at some breakpoint the users will not be displayed anymore or if then below the chat. Also, this is not really HTML5/CSS3 but a simple thing using a container (`width: 100%`) and two divs inside: `#chatEntries {display:inline-block;width:85%;} #chatUsers {display:inline-block;width:15%;}`.

Comment: Yeah but when there is no chat entries, it all pulls together into one mess. I mean when #chatEntries is blank and there is no messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NinoLopezWeb/xpn1zstf/1/)

```
#chatEntries {
display:inline-block;
width:85%;
float:left; }

#chatUsers {
display:inline-block;
width:15%;
float:left; }
```

Comment: Would you by any chance know how to make same thing but vertically?

Comment: I would only know how to accomplish it with viewport units - http://jsfiddle.net/NinoLopezWeb/fguohpma/  However, vh's are not supported by older browsers - http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Answer (score 2):

Accounting for the borders in your illustration I would recommend something like this:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremyhawes/abapyfmq/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="clearfix container">
    <div class="chatEntries"></div>
    <div class="chatUsers">
        <h4>Online Users</h4> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.clearfix:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
 }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
.container {
    background: #000;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
h4 {
    color: #05E9FF;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serf;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.chatEntries,
.chatUsers {
    min-height: 500px;
}
.chatEntries {
    width: 84.8%;
    background: #ccc;
    float: left;
}
.chatUsers {
    position: relative;
    width: 14.8%;
    background: #999;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0.2%;
}
```